# Telegram Telethon Working With Inline Bots

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am trying to query an inline telegram bot in telethon, along the guidelines of the [Docs](https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/bots.html#talking-to-inline-bots). I'm having trouble being able to select one of the outputs on the menu from the bot.
For simplicity, it is an inline bot in a channel about colors and if you query it the string "favorite color poll" a menu pops up with a selection of colors to choose from.
My code is as follows:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetInlineBotResultsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendInlineBotResultRequest

async def main():
    bot_results = client(GetInlineBotResultsRequest(colorbot, colorgroup, 'favorite 
    color poll', ''))
```

But then I get confused how to recognize the values of the options from the bot and to select one. I know it should be something along these lines:

`client(SendInlineBotResultRequest(get_input_peer(colorbot), obtained_query_id, obtained_str_id))`

But I am unsure of how to use these parameters to find the desired output of the bot and to select it.